# Speed up loading json through subprocess

Tags: python, json, algorithm, optimization, subprocess

How can I speed up loading json strings to python dictionary through stdout/subprocess?

For reference, lets take a script `mysubprocess.py`

```
import json
import tempfile


JSON_SIZE = 250000
NUM_JSON = 20


d = [{'a': x, 'b': x, 'c': x, 'd': x, 'e': x, 'f': x} for x in range(JSON_SIZE)]
d = json.dumps(d)


for x in range(NUM_JSON):
    ## Method1
    # print(d)

    ## Method2 and 3
    tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode="w")
    tf.write(d)
    tf.seek(0)
    print(tf.name)
```

in `test.py`

```
import json
import subprocess
import mmap


proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'mysubprocess.py'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    ## Method1
    # d = json.loads(line)

    ## Method2
    # line = line.strip()
    # with open(line, "r") as f:
    #     d = json.loads(f.read())

    ## Method3
    line = line.strip()
    with open(line, "r") as f:
        with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mmap_obj:
            d = json.loads(mmap_obj.read())
```

Where `method1` is just printing the entire json strings into stdout and reading all the string in the main process.  `Method2` is saving the json string to a file and reading the file in the main process.  `Method3` is similar to method2 but loading to memory map.

Executing these in pypy3, I get:

```
Method1: 5.2s
Method2: 5.4s
Method3: 4.8s
```

Is there a more efficient way to get this done?  Is there a way to use mmap and share that address instead of writing to a file then loading it into memory?

Comment: If you have control over mysubprocess.py, try disable the output buffer of it (at least add flush to that print(). This should help improve the performance of method1. Some discussions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering may be helpful.

Comment: multiprocessing.shared_memory https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html  rather than writting to a file or std out you write to a shared memory block, then read it from the other process.

Comment: Dont you have to specify a size?